# Powershell - use CSV as a lookup for replace operation

Tags: csv, powershell, lookup

I have an existing script which reads in a source file and replaces certain characters with new ones. So its pretty much hard coded.

```
(Get-Content $path\$xml_out) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '<ContactCode>PROP</ContactCode>','<ContactCode>OFFICE</ContactCode>'}  | set-content $path\$xml_out
```

What I would like to do is store old and new values in a CSV file (just 2 columns) so that users can make ad-hoc changes. So my CSV will look like this

```
ORGIGINAL_CODE,NEW_CODE
CAREHOME,OFFICE
PROP,EMERG
MAIN,OFFICE
DAY,OFFICE
TELE,TEL
BUSINESS,OFFICE
```

And this is the original file that I am doing the replace upon.

```
CAREHOME
PROP
MAIN
DAY
TELE
BUSINESS
```

I am using import-csv but trying to use a ForEach loop with a Get-Content inside it.

```
$testcsv = import-csv $path\mapping.csv
ForEach ($row in $testcsv)
{
    $field1 = $row.ORGIGINAL_CODE
    $field2 = $row.NEW_CODE
    Echo "$field1 maps to $field2"
    echo "$xml_out"
    (Get-Content $path\$xml_out) | Foreach-Object  {$_ -replace '$field1','$field2'}  | set-content $path\$xml_out
}
```

So instead of replacing field1 with field2 in the source file it is just putting my code

```
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
$_ -replace $field1,$field2
```

I was hoping to end up with

```
OFFICE
EMERG
OFFICE
OFFICE
TEL
OFFICE
```

I suspect that I am not escaping it correctly.

Comment: Please provide us with the "complaint" you mentioned, verbatim.  Also, please provide a [mcve], as many of the variables in your snippet above are not visible (`$CSV`, `$path`, etc.).

Comment: I notice that in your original edit, you had a scriptblock nested inside your `ForEach` loop, which would give the output you see. `Foreach-Object  { {$_ -replace '$field1','$field2'} }`. That's my guess at the cause of your problem - it was just writing the scriptblock to the file with Set-Content. Now you've corrected that mistake in your edit, I bet your code won't give that same problem anymore ...?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be easier to work on the array and output at the end of the loop.

```
$testcsv = Import-Csv $path\mapping.csv
$XmlIn = Get-Content  $path\Scripts\XML.txt
foreach ($row in $testcsv)
{
    $field1 = $row.ORGIGINAL_CODE
    $field2 = $row.NEW_CODE
    Write-Host "$field1 maps to $field2"
    $XmlIn = $XmlIn.Replace($field1,$field2)
}
$XmlIn | Out-File $path\XML.txt
```

Comment: The replace portion didn't work for me so I had to tweak that line and it now works perfectly.
    $testcsv = Import-Csv $path\mapping.csv
$XmlIn = Get-Content $path\source.txt
foreach ($row in $testcsv)
{
    $field1 = $row.ORIGINAL_CODE
    $field2 = $row.NEW_CODE
    Write-Host "$field1 maps to $field2"
    $XmlIn = $XmlIn | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $field1,$field2}
 
}
$XmlIn | Out-File $path\source2.txt